# Munkres Analysis on Manifolds - Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfy the conditions $f(0)=(1,2)$ and
$$ Df(0)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right] $$
Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by the equation
$$g(x,y)=(x+2y+1,3xy).$$
Find $D(gof)(0)$.

Comment: Hint: What is $Dg(1,2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the chain rule, you get $D(g\circ f)(0)={Dg}_{|_{f(0)}}\cdot Df(0)=Dg(1,2)\cdot Df(0)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 \\
3\cdot 2 & 3\cdot 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]\cdot \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 5 \\
6 & 12 & 21 \\
\end{array}
\right]$